# Expectation of conditional expectation eliminates the given information

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I just learned about conditional expectation this week and I am a bit confused on understanding $E(E(X|\mathcal{F}))=E(X)$ where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_0,P)$ is a probability space, $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable and $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{F}_0$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra. The proof is straightforward as the following: by definition of conditional expectation we have for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$, $\int_A X dP=\int_A E(X|\mathcal{F}) dP$. Take $A=\Omega$, then we have the result as desired.

However, I am stuck intuitively that $E(X|\mathcal{F})$ represents a random variable or a "best guess" given information/observables in terms of $\mathcal{F}$. Why did those information disappear when we try to find the best guess of this best guess or the mean of this random variable.

I have one discrete example in mind: consider rolling a dice where $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ and $X$ reads the outcome. Let $\mathcal{F}_0$ be the set of all subsets and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\})$ i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ contains or can observe parity information. Now, $E(X|\mathcal{F})= 3$ if $X$ odd and $4$ if $X$ even and thus $E(E(X|\mathcal{F}))=3.5$ which equals $E(X)$. However, I still don't understand why the given information disappeared.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at $X$ as rv taking values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ we can say that we know everything about $X$ that can be known. But what happens if this information becomes coarser? In the most extreme case we loose sight of all the outcomes. But what we still  have at our disposal as knowledge is its expectation. Actually this constant can be recognized as the degenerated rv $\mathbb E[X|\mathcal F]$ where $\mathcal F$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. When you met earlier $\mathbb EX$ for the first time did you complain about disappearance of info?... I hope this helps.

Comment: In the case you mention yourself we gain some more info about $X$. Next to its expectation we are also informed about its parity. Our information increases if the involved $\sigma$-algebra gets finer and reaches its other extreme if we deal with $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$. A way from $\mathbb EX$ to $X$ you could say

Comment: @drhab Thanks and those are very helpful! In fact, I should interpret $E(X)$ as $E(X|F)$ where $F$ denotes the trivial $\sigma$-algebra i.e. we lost a lot of information. Moreover, we know the smaller $\sigma$-algebra always wins.